# How to determine the Time and Space complexity of rotate string algorithm

Tags: java, string

Can anybody explain the time and space complexity for the below rotate string code snippet.

The book from which this example is taken says that

Complexity Analysis

Time Complexity: O(N^2), where N is the length of A.

Space Complexity: O(N), the space used building A+A.

But I don't understand it. Can anybody please explain?

Example 1:
Input: A = 'abcde', B = 'cdeab'
Output: true

Example 2:
Input: A = 'abcde', B = 'abced'
Output: false

```
public class RotateString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(rotateString("abcd","dabc"));
}
 public static boolean rotateString(String a, String b) {
       return a.length()==b.length() && (a+a).contains(b);
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Space complexity is O(N) because you are adding two strings of length N which will create a new string of length 2*N. Any constant * N is still O(N).

Time complexity is N *N because of the time taken by contains() check. You are checking if string of length 2*N contains another string of length N. To do this using simple for loops, you will have to start checking at each of the 2*N positions and see if next N characters match the target string of length N. So number of comparisons would be 2*N times N = 2 * N ^ 2 ~= O(N^2).

Comment: does `contains` method indeed use simple "for" loops? hard to believe that